# Using WebSockets in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, websocket

I have tried, unsuccessfully, to use websockets in objective-c with the following two libraries:

http://code.google.com/p/unitt/wiki/UnittWebSocketClient

https://github.com/zootreeves/iOS-WebSockets

In both cases I was unable to establish even a basic connection to a server (runnning on localhost).  I was wondering if someone could please provide or point me in the direction of some code that will just simply connect to a server via a websocket and/or perform a handshake.

Ideally, it would be nice if the code could use one of the above libraries, but at this point I'm open to anything that'd work.

I've posted about some issues with UnitT beore but I haven't received any feedback so I'm not sure exactly what step I'm messing up on.  Appreciate any help, thanks!

Comment: This WebSocket library is out of date. The final RFC (6455) is very different from earlier implementations so you should look for something more recent or write your own.

Answer (score 3):

We just released [SocketRocket](https://github.com/square/SocketRocket).  It supports the latest standard, [RFC 6455](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455), which neither ZTWebSocket, nor Unitt does. No CocoaAsyncSocket needed to boot.

Also, [libPusher is experimenting](https://github.com/lukeredpath/libPusher/tree/use-socketrocket-backend) with SocketRocket too.

Comment: Can SocketRocket mark the connection as VOIP connection for using in background based VOIP apps?

Comment: @Gary I am unaware of it being able to. Please file an issue on github with more information if you're interested in the feature.

Comment: libPusher link is broken are you referring to this https://github.com/lukeredpath/libPusher ?

Answer (score 0):

The [libPusher](https://github.com/lukeredpath/libPusher) library uses the [ZTWebSocket](https://github.com/esad/zimt/blob/master/src/ZTWebSocket.m) object. And we have a number of clients who've developed iOS applications against our service. So, the ZTWebSocket object works and should be a good starting point. The libPusher library would be a good reference for usage.

Answer (score 0):

The key to making UnitT work is to find out what version of the specification is your server running. Then you use the correct version for the client. The latest (rev17) of the specification FINALLY allows for multiple versions and having the server send back an appropriate response, but none of the prior versions do. Therefore, you may not receive a meaningful error from the server, just a disconnection. Do you know what version your server is running?